# How can I use CTE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I hope someone can help me. I am trying to get the columns stadt, größtes, mittleres and kleines to display for the cities München and Stuttgart but I am getting all the columns displayed horizontally . München and Stuttgart should be on 2 different rows. Inner join, left join don't seem to work hence I just listed the display result as select * from cte, cte1. How can I get the proper display I want?

```
with cte as
(
select  left(ab.stadt,3) as stadt, avg(gehalt) as mittleres, max(gehalt) as größtes, min(gehalt) as kleinstes
from gehalt g
inner join mitarbeiter m
on m.m_nr=g.m_nr
inner join abteilung ab
on ab.abt_nr=m.abt_nr
where stadt ='Stuttgart'
group by stadt
),
cte1 as
(
select  left(ab.stadt,3) as stadt, avg(gehalt) as mittleres, max(gehalt) as größtes, min(gehalt) as kleinstes
from gehalt g
inner join mitarbeiter m
on m.m_nr=g.m_nr
inner join abteilung ab
on ab.abt_nr=m.abt_nr
where stadt ='München'
group by stadt
)
select * from cte, cte1
```

Comment: No one should be using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple query that would meet your requirements.

```
select  left(ab.stadt,3) as stadt, avg(gehalt) as mittleres, max(gehalt) as größtes, min(gehalt) as kleinstes
from gehalt g
inner join mitarbeiter m
on m.m_nr=g.m_nr
inner join abteilung ab
on ab.abt_nr=m.abt_nr
where stadt in ('Stuttgart','München')
group by stadt
```

if you have to have CTE, you an try something like this

```sql
with cte as 
(select  left(ab.stadt,3) as stadt, avg(gehalt) as mittleres, max(gehalt) as größtes, min(gehalt) as kleinstes
from gehalt g
inner join mitarbeiter m
on m.m_nr=g.m_nr
inner join abteilung ab
on ab.abt_nr=m.abt_nr
group by stadt
)
select * from cte where stadt in ('Stuttgart','München')
```

Although I would recommend the former query, there is no reason to have a CTE.

Comment: Thank you very much but I need to create this as a CTE. Any thoughts?

Comment: updated the answer, could you try this?

Comment: Why "must" you use a CTE, @KikoKiko ?

Comment: I want to try out ctes..I am trying to understand ctes better

Comment: Yes works without the where statement. Thank u Luna Lovegood